# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare min() при объявлении своей функции min

Tags: php

Не могу понят эту ошибку:

```
 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare min()
```

Вот код функции:

```
function min($text){
  $text = strtr($text, 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM', 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm');
  return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не может заново объявить декларацию функции min(). Используйте другое имя

Comment: 0_о не знал что есть функция min

Comment: @Riolu, на [php.net][1] есть описание:

>Если в качестве аргументов передан только один - массив чисел, min() возвращает наименьшее из них. Если первый аргумент - integer или float, то обязательно должен быть хотя бы ещё один. В этом случае функция min() вернёт наименьшее из них. 


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

Comment: @Riolu, а вот Вашу функцию лучше всего заменить на strtolower  польностью — она преобразует строку в нижний регистр. И не надо извращаться с strtr :)

Answer (score 1):

Просто функция `min` вообще-то есть в php и называть свои функции существующими именами нельзя.